# How to extend main template in react-router-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using a react-router-redux. I have a main template with constant header, footer and left bar. May I extends this main template for a different routers? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide code snippet to show what you have and wat you want to have?

Comment: In a short: I have a BaseContainer which render header, footer and left menu. I want that when clicked a "/calendar" we have header, footer and left menu from BaseContainer but main content change from new component (calendar). May I simple do: `class CalendarContainer extends BaseContainer` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question 100% but if you can use the `<Switch>` option in react router for nested routes. [Something like this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch):

```
//from the docs
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  <Route path="/:user" component={User}/>
  <Route component={NoMatch}/>
</Switch>
```

So using that switch you can insert it into your `BaseContainer`

```
class BaseContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="appContainer">
        <Header />
        <LeftMenu />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/:user" component={User}/>
            <Route component={NoMatch}/>
          </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```